# Backbone fetch() send text/html request type instead of json

Tags: backbone.js, yii, marionette

I'm using YiiBackboneBoilerplate. I want to populate a model with data like this:

**--model--**

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone'
    ], function($, _, Backbone) {

        var EvaluateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: 'evaluate/process',
            defaults: {
                title: '',
                state: 1
            }
        });

        return EvaluateModel;
    });
```

**--in my view--**

```
    initialize:function() {
        var result = new Evaluate({id:this.id});
        result.fetch({
            success: function(result, response) {
                JSON.stringify(result.model);
            }
        });
    },
```

**-- Yii action --**

```
public function actionProcess() {
    //I have tryed this
    echo json_encode('test');
    Yii::app()->end();

    //and this
    $this->sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode(array('title' => 'test')));
}
```

and i'm getting textStatus: parsererror and the result returned from the server contains html of the current page

Besides, the fetch() should send a POST request type according to initial setting in the app.js, but the type is 
GET

**--app.js--**

```
// initialize Http object to make backbone work with POST instead of GET
Http.initialize({type:'POST'});
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any documentation refering to `Http.initialize`. Where is that from? Since you're fetching an existing model from the server, Backbone will issue a GET request by default, even when emulating HTTP (http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP).

Second, one thing that might be happening is that you server side framework is ignoring the `application/json` request content-type type, and will only return JSON is you call the `mypage.json` URL (i.e. it's considering only the extension).

By default, Backbond will GET (e.g.) `/api/cars/12` with content-type `application/json` to get the data related to the car model instance qith id 12. Since it requested JSON in the content type, it expects JSON to be returned. Some web frameworks will only have their API return JSON data by default if you instead call the (e.g.) `/api/cars/12.json`. Alternatively, perhaps your API isn't capable of returning JSON (i.e. the API doesn't do it automatically, and you haven't configured it yourself).

Comment: >I don't see any documentation refering to Http.initialize is from http.js which is in app folder \app\js\libs\utils\http.js for the YiiBackboneBoilerplate http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/390/yiibackboneboilerplate-project-setup-for-your-yii-backbonejs-applications/

Comment: > and will only return JSON is you call the mypage.json URL (i.e. it's considering only the extension). Please, explain it a bit more

Comment: I've clarified the JSON call issue. But I still can't find documentation explaining what `Http.initialize` is supposed to do: it isn't mentioned anywhere in the page you linked.

Comment: You can see it here: https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBackboneBoilerplate/blob/master/frontend/www/app/js/libs/utils/http.js

Comment: As far as I can tell, this only sets the *default* HTTP verb. Backbone will still use GET to fetch data, unless you override Backbone.sync with a custom configuration. Take a look at the javascript console to see what is being sent by Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending a jason data from server like this:

```
protected function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $contentType = 'application/json')
{
    // Set the status
    $statusHeader = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . $this->getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($statusHeader);
    // Set the content type
    header('Content-type: ' . $contentType);

    echo $body;
    Yii::app()->end();
}


 protected function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
    {
        $codes = array(
            100 => 'Continue',
            101 => 'Switching Protocols',
            200 => 'OK',
            201 => 'Created',
            202 => 'Accepted',
            203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
            204 => 'No Content',
            205 => 'Reset Content',
            206 => 'Partial Content',
            300 => 'Multiple Choices',
            301 => 'Moved Permanently',
            302 => 'Found',
            303 => 'See Other',
            304 => 'Not Modified',
            305 => 'Use Proxy',
            306 => '(Unused)',
            307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
            400 => 'Bad Request',
            401 => 'Unauthorized',
            402 => 'Payment Required',
            403 => 'Forbidden',
            404 => 'Not Found',
            405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
            406 => 'Not Acceptable',
            407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
            408 => 'Request Timeout',
            409 => 'Conflict',
            410 => 'Gone',
            411 => 'Length Required',
            412 => 'Precondition Failed',
            413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
            414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
            415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
            416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
            417 => 'Expectation Failed',
            500 => 'Internal Server Error',
            501 => 'Not Implemented',
            502 => 'Bad Gateway',
            503 => 'Service Unavailable',
            504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
            505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
        );
        return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
    }
```